# How do I align the title and the navigation on my header?

Tags: css

I new to CSS and I want to ask a question: I have a `<header>` with two elements and I want to align them, the title on the right and the navigation on the left, but I couldn't really hack it alone.

```html
<pre>
  <header >
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <nav class="navigation">
          <ul class="navlist">
              <li>list element</li>
              <li>list element</li>
              <li>list element</li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
</pre>
```

Comment: welcome please share what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
header {
  display: flex;
}

header h1 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="navlist">
            <li>list element</li>
            <li>list element</li>
            <li>list element</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess may you want to achieve in this ui look.
Here is some good article may can helps you [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#parent {
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
 <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="navlist">
            <li>list element</li>
            <li>list element</li>
            <li>list element</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Well done for suggesting the `justify-content: space-between` as this pushes the content to the very edge of the header. :)